# AMPScript Query Update to include additional output fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have the below code that outputs all the Daily_Volumes values for a individual subscriber based on subscriber key. How can it be updated to output a second field for each row its finds?

Eg: Currently it outputs Eg: 100kgMS/day, 200kgMS/day, 50kgMS/day when multiple rows of the same subscriber key is found.

What i need is it to output a second column from that subscriber row

Eg:  Product A = 100kgMS/day, Product B = 200kgMS/day, Product C = 50kgMS/day
Where Product A,B,C is data from column Product_Type

This is the code im currently using

```
%%[ 
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @returnRows, @SubscriberKey, @i 
set @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("_SubscriberKey") 


set @returnRows = -1 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */ 
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Data - Includes Volume", @returnRows, "Daily_Volume asc", "Daily_Volume asc", "Subscriber Key", @SubscriberKey) 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 

if @rowCount > 0 then 

  var @Daily_Volumes 
  set @Daily_Volumes = "" 

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 

     var @Daily_Volume 

     set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */ 
     set @Daily_Volume = field(@row,"Daily_Volume") 

     if @i < @rowCount then 
        set @Daily_Volumes = concat(@Daily_Volumes, @Daily_Volume,"kgMS/day, ") 
     else 
        set @Daily_Volumes = concat(@Daily_Volumes, @Daily_Volume) 
     endif 

  next @i 

else 

   write(concat(" no rows found")) 

endif 

]%%

Your contracted quota is  %%=v(@Daily_Volumes)=%%
```

Thanks 
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to add a `Product_Type` field in your loop and then output it.

```
%%[ 
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @returnRows, @SubscriberKey, @i 
set @SubscriberKey = AttributeValue("_SubscriberKey") 


set @returnRows = -1 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */ 
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Data - Includes Volume", @returnRows, "Daily_Volume asc", "Daily_Volume asc", "Subscriber Key", @SubscriberKey) 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 

if @rowCount > 0 then 

  var @Daily_Volumes 
  set @Daily_Volumes = "" 

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 

     var @Daily_Volume 
     var @Product_Type

     set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */ 
     set @Daily_Volume = field(@row, "Daily_Volume") 
     set @Product_Type = field(@row, "Product_Type") 

     if @i < @rowCount then 
        set @Daily_Volumes = concat(@Daily_Volumes, @Product_Type, " = ", @Daily_Volume,"kgMS/day, ") 
     else 
        set @Daily_Volumes = concat(@Daily_Volumes, @Product_Type, " = ", @Daily_Volume) 
     endif 

  next @i 

else 

   write(concat(" no rows found")) 

endif 

]%%

Your contracted quota is  %%=v(@Daily_Volumes)=%%
```